# How can I copy a formula in a automatic way in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a main sheet in witch I copy it and create different versions, kind of like simulating different results.

But every time I want to change something in the main sheet, I have to go in all the other sheets I created and changed.

I don't know if it is possible, but the best way for me would be to create a formula like this:

copyFormula(Sheet1!V2) -> And bringed the exactly same result as if I had gone to Sheet1 copied V2 and pasted it this cell.

I tried to create this formula but failed consistently.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to manipulate the properties of the sheets.

Here is a [reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet) where you can create those actions.

> The Sheets API allows you to create sheets, delete sheets, and control
>   their properties. The examples on this page illustrate how some common
>   sheet operations can be achieved with the API.
>
> In these examples, the placeholders `spreadsheetId` and `sheetId` are
>   used to indicate where you would provide those IDs. The [spreadsheet
>   ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id) can be discovered from the spreadsheet URL; the sheet ID can be
>   obtained from the [spreadsheet.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) method.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading) on how you can read the formula you are needing in the entire sheets.

> The Sheets API allows you to read values from cells, ranges, sets of
>   ranges and entire sheets. The examples on this page illustrate how
>   some common read operations can be achieved with the
>   [spreadsheets.values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values) collection of this API. You can also read
>   cell values using the [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) method, but in most cases
>   using [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) or
>   [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) is easier to use.